# how to change the parent div's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to CSS. I want to apply background color for `div`. But the div height is zero. `div` has child elements too.
Here is my code. I added float to that `ul,li` elements.I searched so many sites I applied clear to the `div` ,but its not changing.

```
 <div id="menulinks">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="#">projectCategoraization</a>
            <div id="submenu_pc">
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">dgfdg</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">tutyu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ert45</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">7y56uty</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**style**

```
#submenu_pc {
    width:240px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
.dropdown {
    float:left;
}
.dropdown li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
}
.dropdown ul li {
    float:none;
}
```

**script** is

```
$(function(){
  $(".dropdown li").hover(function(){
        //alert("soumya");
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('#submenu_pc').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra '</div>'?

Comment: Your first `<ul>` and `<li>` is not closed

Comment: Add JSFiddle like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/U6JGn/) created for you

Comment: why are you using jquery to display submenu on hover? css can do that efficiently.

Comment: This is not a semantic markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.submenu` has `position: absolute` which means its parent has a height of `0`. Remove `position: absolute` and assign a background color to the parent; that should do it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/QMXQF/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding background color to the UL with class of submenu

```
.submenu
{
    background-color:aqua;  
}
```

Comment: actually i am getting div (#submenu_pc) with 0 px...but this height should be height of ul(based on div contents).

Comment: Why dont you just apply the color to the submenu ul then?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS and remove the script completely!

```
#menulinks{
    overflow:hidden;
    background: red; // choose your color
}

#submenu_pc {
    width:240px;
    display:none;
}

.dropdown li:hover #submenu_pc{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown {
    float:left;
}
.dropdown li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
.dropdown ul li {
    float:none;
}
```